# String[].clear in Android 1.5

Tags: java, android

I am trying to port some Android 2.x code to Android 1.5, here is the problematic line:

```
String[] myStringsArray = ...
...
myStringsArray.clear();
```

String[].clear() is not defined in Android 1.5, leading to this error:

```
[javac] MyClass.java:1692: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : method clear()
[javac] location: class java.lang.String[]
[javac]         myStringsArray.clear();
```

What is the best I could use instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `java.util.Arrays` utility class.

`Arrays` provides a static method called `fill()` which takes your `Array` as the first parameter and the `Object` or primitive to fill the array as the second parameter.

You could fill your Array with `null` like this.

```
String myStringsArray[] = ...

Arrays.fill(myStringsArray, null);
```

Now every position in the Array is null.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such method `clear()` defined for array.You can go for [`List<String>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and use `clear()`

Comment: I would rather not change the type of this variable, it has huge repercussions on many other classes.

Comment: @Nicoal: arrays never have a `clear()` method in Java. What do you want to achieve with this call?

Comment: then just set it with `null` and in rest code if required add nullity check or you can simple create a new array that will create the prior object reference less so ready for GC and you will have a new array which is cleared

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method to clear String[]

you can use new String[0]; to clear values from you string array